# How can I calculate 3 time inputs?

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, timedelta

I am not a native English speaker, so I apologize in advance for my English.
As a beginner I want to create a simple program which calculates the time that I worked for a day. With `Tkinter` I so far created 3 entries (starting time, lunch break, finishing time), which each require one time input(%H:%M) and an okay button. When I press the okay button it should calculate the difference between starting time and finishing time and then subtract it with the lunch time.

The problem is, I can only calculate the difference between the starting and finishing time. it gives me a warning:

> "Expected type 'delta', got datetime instead"

If I run the program, I get this:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.datetime'"

```py
import datetime

def ok(Event = None):
    try:
        start_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_start_time.get()), "%H:%M")
        lunch_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_lunch_time.get()), "%H:%M")
        close_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_closing_time.get()), "%H:%M")
    x = close_to_time - start_to_time -lunch_to_time


    print(x)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you try to calculate. If you want to subtract time spend on lunch then you have to calculate  `lunch_finish - lunch_start` and then you may have `(close_to_time - start_to_time) - (lunch_finish - lunch_start)`

Comment: if `lunch_to_time` describe how long you spend on lunch (not at what time you start lunch) then you have to use `datetime.timedelta(hours=..., minutes=...)` for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. i just realised, that the lunchtime is a timedelta, as you said. The problem now is, that it is an Entry and i dont know how to convert it into a timedelta

Comment: in answer I made example which converts string from Entry (ie. "1:30") to `timedelta`

Comment: I added example how to use midnight to convert `datetime` to `timedelta`

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. I apreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have two situations

```
x = (work_stop - work_start) - (lunch_stop - lunch_start)
```

But it needs two values for lunch

Or

```
x = (work_stop - work_start) - time_spend_on_lunch
```

but here `time_spend_on_lunch_start` has to be `timedelta` instead of `datetime`

---

Example 1

```
import datetime

work_start = datetime.datetime.strptime("8:00", "%H:%M")
work_stop =  datetime.datetime.strptime("16:00", "%H:%M")

lunch_start = datetime.datetime.strptime("12:00", "%H:%M")
lunch_stop  = datetime.datetime.strptime("13:30", "%H:%M")

x = (work_stop - work_start) - (lunch_stop - lunch_start)

print(x)
```

Example 2

```
import datetime

work_start = datetime.datetime.strptime("8:00", "%H:%M")
work_stop =  datetime.datetime.strptime("16:00", "%H:%M")

time = "1:30"
time = time.split(':')
time = [int(x) for x in time]

time_spend_on_lunch = datetime.timedelta(hours=time[0], minutes=time[1])

x = (work_stop - work_start) - time_spend_on_lunch

print(x)
```

You can also define `midnight` to convert `datetime` to `timedelta`

```
import datetime

midnight = datetime.datetime.strptime("0:00", "%H:%M")

time = "1:30"
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M")

time_spend_on_lunch = time - midnight

print( time_spend_on_lunch )
print( type(time_spend_on_lunch) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when you subtract two `datetime` objects (`close_to_time` and `start_to_time`) you get a `timedelta` object as a result which no longer represents a date but a duration between 2 dates (eg. number of hours and minutes between `close_to_time` and `start_to_time`).

You can only subtract `datetimes` from `datetimes` and `timedeltas` from `timedeltas` and the result will always be a `timedelta`. Since the amount of time you take for lunch wouldn't be a specific time but a period of time, it is better suited to be represented by a `timedelta` which you could get by subtracting the lunch start time from the lunch end time like so:

```
start_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_start_time.get()), "%H:%M")
lunch_start_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_lunch_start_time.get()), "%H:%M")
lunch_end_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_lunch_end_time.get()), "%H:%M")
close_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_closing_time.get()), "%H:%M")

opening_duration = close_to_time - start_to_time
lunch_duration = lunch_end_to_time - lunch_start_to_time

work_duration = opening_duration - lunch_duration

print(work_duration)
```

Of course in this case you will need to get both start and end times for lunch from the input.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It's maybe a dumb question but I'm at the beginning stages of coding

Answer (score -1):

**Assuming**

- `start_to_time` is the **time of day** you started work
- `lunch_to_time` is the **length** of your lunch break
- `close_to_time` is the **time of day** you finished work

**This should work**

```
def ok(Event = None):
    try:
        start_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_start_time.get()), "%H:%M")
        lunch_duration = str( input_lunch_time.get() )
        lunch_to_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=lunch_duration[0], minutes=lunch_duration[1])
        close_to_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(input_closing_time.get()), "%H:%M")
    x = (close_to_time - start_to_time) - lunch_to_time

    print(x)
    return x
```

Comment: `Entry` gives string like "1:30" so you will have `minute=":"`. And `timedelta` expects integers, not strings so you get error.